# How did Thanos survive a thermonuclear bomb?

Tags: marvel, comics, the-infinity-gauntlet

In the end of *Infinity Gauntlet* (1991) comic series, Thanos detonated a thermonuclear bomb present in his belt.

[image]

[image]

But, we later learned that he had actually tried to fool others and was perfectly okay.

How did he survive such explosion? Is his body really that strong (I doubt it because even his Titan brother who knows him better believed that he got killed by the explosion)? Or, did he use other methods like teleportation to survive?

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned [here](http://marvel.com/universe/Thanos#axzz5BWMLQVMr):

> Thanos possesses the superhuman physiology of all Eternals, granting him superhuman strength, endurance, reflexes, and agility. His skin in nearly ***invulnerable***, particularly against heat, cold, electricity, ***radiation***, toxins, ageing, and disease.

My initial guess is his invulnerability against radiation. This could be one reason how/why he survived.

However, I realized something else. In the end of [issue#6](http://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Infinity-Gauntlet-1991/Issue-6?id=44288&readType=1) when Adam visits Thanos on an unnamed planet, he says something on the lines of: "*Thanos is merely a piece in the mosaic and without him, the picture is incomplete*". So, my second guess here is that Adam, who now wields the Infinity Gauntlet might have protected Thanos or brought him back.

[image]

Comment: When a nuclear weapon detonates on your head, you need to first worry about extreme temperature..

Comment: More recently, in the 2006 series, Earths Eternals are demonstrated to be rebuilt in celestial machinery in far flung places back on Earth. It's possible that a mechism like this may have been posited back then, and that this planet contains that machinery pertaining to Thanos, even though I'm fairly certain this planet isn't meant to be Titan.

Comment: @Don'tPanic well he's also immune to high temperatures so, maybe he did survive the blast. or the latter

Comment: BTW, as per later conversation between Adam Warlock and Thanos, it seems Adam Warlock didn't have any hand in the survival of Thanos. It was Thanos' idea to fool everyone and he even admitted his mistake that he wrongly assumed that he could fool Adam Warlock.

Answer (score 3):

Earlier in the series, you find out Thanos has a large array of powers acquired through many means, science, genetics, bionics etc. Shortly before that he demonstrates teleporting away from a large battle.

So, he simply outsmarted the heroes by faking his death and teleporting away at the last moment.

Furthermore, others have correctly pointed out that Thanos admitted he fooled everyone except for Adam Worlock.

Now, *can* he survive a nuke? I don't know; maybe, however, Occam's Razor says he simply teleported away.